# Any way to test my pool connection from the command line?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, cpu-mining, connection

I'm on a Mac High Sierra.  I'm trying to get this project to work on my local machine -- https://github.com/cryptonoter/CryptoNoter .  I'm having some issues getting the server proxy to connect to the pool and as a sanity check, I was wondering if there was any way I could test my connection to the pool using traditional Unix command line tools.  I was looking to use XMR pool (https://xmrpool.net/#/help/getting_started) .  It lists some hosts and ports but I'm unclear how I would use that information to test my connection to a pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pools use JSON over HTTP. To test connectivity, you can simply use curl on the mining port advertised in the "Getting started" page of most pools. This will cause an error message on the pool side since you don't "talk stratum", but is otherwise innocuous.

Another possibility, which doesn't use "traditional Unix command line tools" but still uses command line tools is to use a CPU miner (for example Wolf's at https://github.com/hyc/cpuminer-multi) to connect and attempt to mine. This will ensure that the server on the other side is a working Monero pool.

Comment: These "getting started" pages are very vague.  Going the curl route, can you give an example of a curl command that would connect to such a pool?  It doesn't have to do anything other than connect but I'd still like to see how it works.

Comment: It's as simple as `curl URL`. You shouldn't get any data back, but no error/timeout either.